# Sass error : ionic sass primary isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

im trying to add a background color to my ionic app, but now I'm facing this issue
my code is

in variable.scss

```
$colors: (
      primary:    #4486F9,

    );
```

and error

```
sass: D:/hybrid_app/ionictest/accounts/src/theme/variables.scss, line: 36
        (primary: #4486F9) isn't a valid CSS value.

  L36:  $colors: (
  L37:    primary:    #4486F9,
```

Using

> Ionic Framework: 3.6.0
>   Ionic App Scripts: 2.1.3
>   Angular Core: 4.1.3
>   Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
>   Node: 7.10.0

Comment: It might be having a problem with the trailing comma? I'm guessing you're following [this guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/theming-your-app/)?

Comment: Could you put the whole scss file? I think the you made a typo error somewhere down this line and it invalidates the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is given below:

```
$colors: (
    primary: (base: #4486F9, contrast:#000)
);
```